# GET events from PUBLIC Google calendar WITHOUT OAuth, just with API Key?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

As the title suggests.How can I GET events from PUBLIC Google calendar **WITHOUT** using OAuth, just with API Key ?

Below is not working.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarid}/events?key={API Key}

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share the code your doing the request with?

Comment: I entered the above in a browser. Obviously substituting the braces for appropriate values. Thanks

Comment: @kvothe__: Were you able to find the solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, you need to set the following 3 settings:

1. Make your calendar public
2. Set your API key app-restrictions within the Google API Console to allow your application and/or website domain to make requests.
3. Make sure your API key has access to the calendar API, this setting can be found on the same page.

Comment: I did all these things, yet im still seeing 401. It says login required. "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"